# Autoload doesn't works if I try to create an instance of a class from inside other function

Tags: php, class, load, autoload

helper.php :  Required at the top of index.php

```
function __autoload($className) {

    $path = ROOT_DIR.'/class/'.strtolower(trim($className)).'.class.php';

    if (file_exists($path)) {
        require_once($path);
    }
}

function load_libs($class_variable_name) {

    global $session;
    global $_libs;

    $_libs[$class_variable_name] = new $class_variable_name($session);

    return $_libs[$class_variable_name];
}
```

From index.php I create an instance of a class :

```
new some_class_one();
```

No problem, it loads class file via __autoload.

But, in case that I call :

```
load_libs('some_class_two');
```

I getting error :
    Fatal error: Class 'some_class_two' not found in C:\wamp\www\helper.php on line

Any idea what to do ?

Comment: try : $arg = 'some_class_two'; load_libs($arg);

Comment: Yes: make sure that your `__autoload` is called, then find out why `file_exists($path)` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my machine and it works perfectly. I could not replicate the issue. This is the version of PHP I'm running:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.4.17 (cli) (built: Aug 25 2013 02:03:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

I would suggest that you remove the `.class` from your filenames. It's better to use namespaces and have the namespace/class name match the filesystem. Other than that, either your `ROOT_DIR` is incorrect or your file is located in the wrong place.